# Fetch text inside of a Pre Tag which is not having any id

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am doing web scraping and want to fetch the text inside the Pre tag in vba. but unfortunately the pre tag is not having any id. Can someone guide me how to do that

```
<form method="post" name="statusummary" action="/servstat" id="statserv">
<pre>
....
....
....

</pre>
</form>
```

Comment: `document.getelementsbyTagName("form")(0).getelementsbyTagName("pre")` may work.  If there are  multiple forms then you may need to adjust the `(0)`

Comment: Might be a help to anyone to see the VBA cod you has so far ;) I know a lot of ways how it might be possible. But no code no answer :) Tims Answer is cool, for sure there is a twis by that. He is thinking in Javascript which is  possible but tricky :) He suggest mixed language programming-.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining id with pre tag using an adjacent sibling combinator (assuming your indentation is correct) i.e. positional matching

```
ie.document.querySelector("#statserv + pre")
```

Comment: Thanks guys for quick response, i will try and will keep posted..

Comment: Thank you all buddies for guiding me. Below code worked for me and iam able to fetch the text inside pr tag..

ie.Document.querySelector("#statserv").innertext

Comment: Is the pre tag inside (rather than next to) the statsserv then?